# How to copy nested arrays and making sure that the copy is a complete dup of the original

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, deep-copy, dup

Is there an easy way to copy a nested Array so that every object in the array will be a 'dup' of the original? I recently run into this:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
irb(main):002:0> b = a.dup
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
irb(main):003:0> a[0][1] = 99
=> 99
irb(main):004:0> a
=> [[1, 99], [3, 4]]
irb(main):005:0> b
=> [[1, 99], [3, 4]]
irb(main):006:0> a[0] = [101,102]
=> [101, 102]
irb(main):007:0> a
=> [[101, 102], [3, 4]]
irb(main):008:0> b
=> [[1, 99], [3, 4]]
```

So while the first level of arrays in `a` were individual objects, their content were not, `a[0][1]` is still equal to `b[0][1]`. A general solution don't even have to know how deeply an array is nested. Walking through every object and make it a dup of itself sounds a bit brute-force to me.

Comment: In an ideal world, you wouldn't need to duplicate it, because you wouldn't do any modification of objects. However, if you're working with a legacy app where object modification goes on, it's a legitimate question.

Comment: I'm working on some chaotic function visualization, where one value in the array is depending on the previous value and calculation is iterated a few times. I have to do the calculation atomic on the whole array level (which represents the visible area), so I have 2 arrays and I make calculations from the first, and put the result to the second (in the same position), and when the current iteration ends, I should make the 'present' array a 'previous' one, this when a simple Pascal-like array copy needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd have never thought of it.